# Dissociation of silver chloride in a solution

Tags: aqueous-solution, precipitation, silver

When silver chloride is exposed to light it can dissociate to silver metal and atomic chlorine. It might be a silly question, but could the chlorine go back into the solution as chloride ions ? if so is this likely to occur? does the outcome change if the solution is being boiled?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes and no. Silver chloride doesn't "dissociate", it *decomposes* into silver metal and dissolved chlorine.  The chloride reacts with the water to form hydrochloric acid and hypochlorous acid as shown below:
$$\ce{2AgCl_{(s)} +H_2O_{(l)} ->[h\nu] 2Ag_{(s)} + Cl_2_{(aq)} +H_2O_{(l)}->2Ag_{(s)} + HCl_{(aq)} + HClO_{(aq)}}$$

Comment: Temperature makes a *big* difference in solubility of AgCl: it increases by over an order of magnitude from room temperature to boiling. See http://www.saltlakemetals.com/Solubility_Of_Silver_Chloride.htm

Comment: States of aggregation should not be subscripted, it is not wrong, but the [recommendations (Sec. 2.1.)](http://pac.iupac.org/publications/pac/pdf/1982/pdf/5406x1239.pdf) are different.

Comment: It really seems to me that for clarity there should be two separate reaction schemes. Making the whole thing one long line is just confusing.