How does Ag+ interact with Cl-?
$\ce{Ag+}$ is an effective antimicrobial, but $\ce{AgCl}$ is not.
Would mixing $\ce{Ag+}$ with hydrochloric acid cause all of the silver ions to form $\ce{AgCl}$, or is there a saturation point whereby some $\ce{Ag+}$ is still viable? I am wondering whether ingestion of ionic silver as a systemic antimicrobial would be useless once it combined with gastric acids, in that the ions might become unavailable to be absorbed into the bloodstream from the intestines. Perhaps a sufficient quantity of $\ce{Ag+}$, higher in concentration than the number of $\ce{Cl-}$ and other suitable negative ions, would allow for enough to get through the gastric acids as a free ion to remain effective.
Will silver ions that have been hydrolyzed into distilled water bind to the chloride ions in Himalayan salt when it is added to the ionic silver water at room temperature? If so, would this $\ce{AgCl}$ combination continue until all of the silver ions became $\ce{AgCl}$ precipitate, given sufficient $\ce{NaCl}$? I assume this would depend on the ratio of $\ce{Ag+}$ to $\ce{Cl-}$. With 10ppm ionic silver, is there a way to calculate how much salt to add to avoid losing all the $\ce{Ag+}$ as $\ce{AgCl}$ precipitate? If this mixture is heated, but not boiled, would that affect the interaction?
If MSM and DMSO are added to a mixture of ionic silver and Himalayan salt, would there be any other significant interactions? Or, if salt does create an abundance of $\ce{AgCl}$ and was therefore omitted, would there be significant interactions between $\ce{Ag+}$, MSM and DMSO? My question is aimed at whether this combination might alter the therapeutic effects of these compounds when used separately.
This is my first question, so I apologize if I'm not appropriately providing all the necessary information. Thank you!

You ask a number of different questions. I don't understand how hydrolysis relates to preparation of the silver ion solution. Adding table salt or hydrochloric acid are different things but the end result would be precipitation of silver chloride, but see this.

see also: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/41957/dissociation-of-silver-chloride-in-a-solution?rq=1

No. There is no "saturation point" where by "$\ce{Ag+}$ does not react with $\ce{Cl-}$ ions in solution". As soon as both ions meet in solution, they produce a white  $\ce{AgCl}$ precipitate. The tiny remaining amounts of $\ce{Ag+}$ and $\ce{Cl-}$ in solution depends on the $\ce{AgCl}$ solubility product, which is $1.8*10^{-10}$. As a consequence, as soon as one of these two ions is in excess, the concentration of the second ion in solution is less than one milligram per liter. This has no therapeutic effect.
